# Regex how to add string to a beginning of src attribute

Tags: regex

Just like in the title. I need to add to src attribute in a lot of files this line in the beginning: - `"http://media.cdn.com/"`

So for example I got: -

```
src="/images/galeri/image1.jpg"
```

I would like to change it to: -

```
src="http://media.cdn.com/images/galeri/image1.jpg"
```

How can i achieve that ? To add additional string (`"http://media.cdn.com/"`)in the beginning of a lot of src attributes ?

Comment: I got about 800 files in directory (static html files). All i what to do is to add to all src attributes in all those files ''http://media.cdn.com/'' at the begining of each src attribute. I tried something like this: (?<=src=')(.*)(?=') butthat will erase content in src attribue and replace that with http://media.cdn.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using simple sed command:

```
sed "sXsrc=\"Xsrc=\"http://media.cdn.com/Xg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply regex to multiple files at once:

```
$ perl -p -i -e 's/src="\/([^"]+)"/src="http:\/\/media.cdn.com\/\1"/g' *
```